# how to remove from a list from a combo box

Tags: java

When trying to write the following code, it comes up with 3 errors. Syntax error on token 'else', insert 'assignmentoperator expression' to complete assignment and that cannot convert from string to boolean. This is for a combo box and when I choose from the combo box, I want to remove the other sites from a list.  'site' is a variable in main and c.site is a parameter in another agent. Can someone explain what to do.

```
if ( site ) {
    if ( c.site.equals( "x" ) ) {
        cavernIterator.remove();
        continue;
    }
}
else {
    if ( c.site.equals( "y" ) ) {
    cavernIterator.remove();
    continue;
    }
}
else {
    if ( c.site.equals( "z" ) ) {
        cavernIterator.remove();
        continue;
        }
    }
else {
    ( c.site.equals( "a" ) ) {
    cavernIterator.remove();
    continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide site.
System.out.println("Site: " + site);

Answer (score 2):

You can't have several `else` blocks for the same `if`. Each `else` block has to be attached to its own `if`:

```
if(a) {
    ...
} else {
    if (b) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        if (c) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or, with a shorthand for all this, you can have a single-statement block inside the `else`, so it looks like this:

```
if (a) {
    ...
}
else if (b) {
    ...
}
else if (c) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

This second one is nearly the same as the first, as it takes advantage of not having to wrap a statement block in braces if your statement block only has single statement, like this:

```
if (myCondition)
    System.out.println("My condition passed");
else
    System.out.println("My condition did not pass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Else if should be written this way :

```java
if (...) {
    // Code here
} else if (...) {
    // Code here
} else {
    // Code here
}
```

Also your cases seem similar

```java
String[] sites = {"x","y","z","a"};
boolean contains = Arrays.stream(sites).anyMatch(c.site::equals);
if (contains) {
    cavernIterator.remove();
    continue;
}
```

EDIT: Considering site is a string

```java
String site = "x"; // Default value provided
String[] sites = {"x","y","z","a"};
boolean condition = site.equals(c.site) && Arrays.stream(sites).anyMatch(c.site::equals);
if (condition) {
    cavernIterator.remove();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: The second code removes everything from the list. I just want to remove the other 3 when 1 is chosen. With the first code, it still says cannot convert string to boolean

Comment: @Flygerian if (site) ... site is a string which cannot be converted to a boolean

Comment: @Flygerian .remove() is surely the cause of removing everything from the list ;)

Comment: what should I write instead then, or should i change the parameter or the variable]

Comment: Provide its value and type.
What's the declaration of site in main ?

Comment: its a string and its initial value is "x". the combo box is linked with this variable, which is main. The information where the site is, is in a parameter in another agent

Comment: @Flygerian so what does `if(site)`mean ? 
What are you trying to achieve with this condition ? What do you want to check ?

Comment: so the combo box needs to be linked to a variable in main, so thats the site. So the 'if(site)' is to relate the variable site to the parameter site. Or is there another way to do this

Comment: Do you mean `if (site.equals(c.site))` ?

Comment: yes, but i need for the c.site to equal either x,y,z,a so how do i write that part

Comment: @Flygerian I already answered that.
I check that any String in `sites` contains one matching c.site through `.anyMatch(c.site::equals);`

Comment: Ok Thanks for all the help. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ( site ) {
        if ( c.site.equals( "x" ) ) {
        }
   }
```

equals

```
    if(site && c.site.equals("x")){
    }
```

And your last else is messed up.

Likely look on some Java tutorials because you write the least efficient way possible. This is your code in short:

```
if (site && (c.site.equals("x") || c.site.equals("y") || c.site.equals("z") || c.site.equals("a"))) {
    cavernIterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Your code comes up with the error 'the operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) String, boolean'

Comment: @Flygerian as mentionned above, if site is a string it cannot be compared using &&

Comment: then what should site be then

Comment: Depending on what you want to use, a boolean, a string, any object ...
What is your if condition ?
if (site != null) ? if (!site.equals("a")) ?

Comment: I want it to be string as thats what it is. my if condition is if it is the site, i want to remove the other sites

Comment: Why?  'site' will always be 'site' untill you change it. You need to get the selected site and compare it with #equals(site).